# Excel COUNTIFS between date range

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, countif

How do I count between a date range using COUNIFS?  The dates are set as columns The_Date_Start and The_Date_End.

My formula is

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!C:C,[@Tel],Sheet2!A:A,"<="&[@[The_Date]])
```

I have tried something like the below but doesn't work

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!C:C,[@Tel],Sheet2!A:A,"=>"&[@[The_Date_Start]],"<="&[@[The_Date_End]])
```

Comment: Test the constraints separately - that way you can work out which part is causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS([ColToCount], ">="&[@End], [ColToCount], "<="&[@Start])
```

Note that all the ranges should be of same length. In your formula, they are of different lengths